# Outlook MAPI in C++ application: Find contacts by name

Tags: c++, outlook

I have a C++ application to retrieve Outlook contacts: (local & exchange) users & distribution lists)

I got an interface file 'msoutl.tlh' by using :

```
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\mso.dll" named_guids

#import "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSOUTL.OLB" no_namespace rename("Folder", "OlkFolder") rename("CopyFile", "OlkCopyFile") rename("GetOrganizer", "GetOrganizerAE")
```

There I have all Outlook MAPI classes I can use

With that, I can get all contacts from Outlook client(removed NULL and HRESULT checks) :

```
    _ApplicationPtr pApp;
_NameSpacePtr _nsPtr = pApp->GetNamespace(_bstr_t("MAPI"));
AddressListsPtr lists = _nsPtr->GetAddressLists();
AddressListPtr list;
char s[256];

for (int i = 1; i <= lists->GetCount(); i++)
{
    list = lists->Item(i);
    AddressEntries* pAddrEntries = nullptr;
    AddressEntryPtr addEntryPtr = pAddrEntries->GetFirst();
    while (addEntryPtr)
    {
        _ExchangeUserPtr pExchangeUser = nullptr;
        BSTR bstrPropName = nullptr;
        BSTR bstrPropAddr = nullptr;
        BSTR bstrSMTPAddr = nullptr;
        OlAddressEntryUserType userType;
        AddressEntriesPtr pAaddrEntries = nullptr;

        addEntryPtr->get_Name(&bstrPropName);
        addEntryPtr->get_Address(&bstrPropAddr);
        userType = addEntryPtr->GetAddressEntryUserType();

        switch (userType)
        {
        case olExchangeUserAddressEntry: // 0
        {
            addEntryPtr->raw_GetExchangeUser(&pExchangeUser);
            pExchangeUser->get_PrimarySmtpAddress(&bstrSMTPAddr);
            sprintf(s, "EXCHANGE USER: %S (%S) \n", (WCHAR*)bstrPropName, (WCHAR*)bstrSMTPAddr);
            break;
        }
        case olExchangeDistributionListAddressEntry: // 1
        {
            if (S_OK == addEntryPtr->get_Members(&pAaddrEntries))
            {
                _ExchangeDistributionListPtr exchangeDistrList = nullptr;
                addEntryPtr->raw_GetExchangeDistributionList(&exchangeDistrList);
                exchangeDistrList->get_PrimarySmtpAddress(&bstrSMTPAddr);
                sprintf(s, "EXCHANGE DISTRIBUTION LIST: %S (%S) - %d members \n", (WCHAR*)bstrPropName, (WCHAR*)bstrSMTPAddr, pAaddrEntries->GetCount());
            }
            break;
        }

        case olOutlookContactAddressEntry: // 10
        {
            sprintf(s, "OUTLOOK CONTACT: %S (%S) \n", (WCHAR*)bstrPropName, (WCHAR*)bstrPropAddr);
            break;
        }
        case olOutlookDistributionListAddressEntry: // 11
        {
            addEntryPtr->get_Members(&pAaddrEntries);
            sprintf(s, "OUTLOOK DISTRIBUTION LIST: %S - %d members \n", (WCHAR*)bstrPropName, pAaddrEntries->GetCount());
            break;
        }
        default: break;
        }
    }
}
```

This works perfectly (i have all contacts retrieved from Outlook).

My problem is to resolve names (i need to filter by text), to list only those users which match.

I could do it loading all users & looping, but with lots of contacts would be really slow

And I can see there are methods for that, such as Find or Restrict. But I have no success.

Once i have a list, i have:

```
MAPIFolderPtr mapiFolder = list->GetContactsFolder();
if (mapiFolder)
{
    _ItemsPtr folderItems = mapiFolder->Items;
    if (folderItems)
    {
        _Items* pItems;
        BSTR bstrPropID = A2BSTR("*");
        HRESULT hr = folderItems->raw_Restrict(bstrPropID, &pItems);
    }
}
```

I have 2 problems:

- Only in the Outlook Local contacts list i get a valid MAPIFolderPtr item (other lists such as exchange users returns NULL)
- When I have MAPIFolderPtr, mapiFolder->Items returns a valid value (number of contacts in this list), but pItems is NULL...

I tried also with

```
folderItems->Restrict("*")
folderItems->Find(bstrPropID);
```

but i got an exception ('Condition is not valid') in both cases

And with

```
IDispatch * pDisp;
folderItems->raw_Find(bstrPropID, &pDisp);
```

but pDisp is NULL;

Any help to resolve names in Outlook Contact lists?

Thanks,
Diego

Comment: Of course - AddressList.GetContactsFolder returns a valid MAPIFolder only if the list of based on one of the Contacts folders on your mailbox. There is no folder in case of a GAL container.

Comment: To resolve a name, you can use Application.Session.CreateRecipient / Recipient.Resolve

Comment: Thanks for your help. Now this works but when there is only one recipient which matches the pattern... I also need a list of contacts when more than one matches... I have tried Find or Restrict but no success, i don't find which object i must use...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help, Dmitry, I got it:

I have my addrBook, I get the root container (IAddrBook::OpenEntry), and I get a table with all the address books (IABContainer::GetHierarchyTable)

Then I got the container (IAddrBook::OpenEntry), got the contents table (IABContainer::GetContentsTable) and applied the PR_ANR restriction to find a string, such as "di" (to find 'Diego Doñate' or 'Diana xxx').

Answer (score 1):

To resolve to a single recipient, you can use `Application.Session.CreateRecipient` / `Recipient.Resolve`.

The only way to get multiple matches is to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) and do what Outlook does when resolving names and getting an ambiguous match -  use [PR_ANR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/address-book-restrictions) restriction on a particular container. MAPI address book providers do not support conmlex restrictions the way store providers do. `PR_ANR` is really your best bet.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language, I am its author) is an option, it exposes [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm).[AddressBook](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdoaddressbook.htm).`ResolveNameEx` and [RDOAddressList](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm).`ResolveNameEx` that return a collection of matches.

Comment: Thanks! Reading about restrictions in the documentation, I can see that:

From IMAPIContainer I get a IMAPITable:
 IMAPIContainer::GetContentsTable(ULONG ulFlags, LPMAPITABLE FAR * lppTable);
And with the table I can Restrict the contents:
 IMAPITable::Restrict(LPSRestriction lpRestriction, ULONG ulFlags);
I suppose that LPSRestriction has:
 rt = RES_CONTENT
 res = SContentRestriction (with custom data to match)

But I don't know how to get the IMAPIContainer from my IMAPISession or my IAddrBook...

Is that correct?

Comment: You can get IMAPISession from Namespace.MAPIOBJECT in OOM, then open the address list using IAMPISession::OpenEntry() passing the address list entry id.